# python circular importing in the first line?

Tags: python, import, python-import, circular-dependency, circular-reference

Let's say I have 2 python script

the first one:

```
#X.py
import Y
a = 'list'
print('finish')
```

and the second one:

```
#Y.py
import X
z = X.a
print(z)
```

Question 1:

When I execute X.py first,there's nothing wrong with the code,but when I execute the Y.py first,an error occurs,but why?

Question 2:

I've looked up some answers for circular importing,but I still don't understand.In this case,starting from X.py,the first line is "import Y",then the program should goes to compile Y.py.The first line in Y.py is "import X",so I guess the program goes to X.py again,then goes to Y.py ，and so on.....
But why there is no endless loop happens?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your first question:**

You are getting an `AttributeError` because when you run `Y.py` it first executes the import statement which is to `import X`. Then, when importing `X`, the `import Y` statement is executed first in `X.py`, so the code looks for the variable `a` in  `Y.py` instead of `X.py`. You can test this by commenting out `import Y` in `X.py` then it will work.

**To answer your second question:**

A module is loaded only once, regardless of the number of times it is imported. This prevents the module execution from happening over and over again if multiple imports occur.